# value attribute: warning by Eclipse

Tags: html, eclipse

I am currently moving from Komodo Edit to Eclipse. I have created a php project that works well, but for a few warning I am now correcting. I am experiencing a difficulty here :

```
<td> <input type="text" name="tfCode" id="tfCode" value="" size="5" oninput="jFiltre_Champ(event,'NUM1');" tabindex="2"> </td>
```

This line causes a warning by Eclipse (4.2.2), i.e.: "Undefined attribute name (oninput)." while execution (user's data filtering on input) by browsers runs smoothly.

The file is declared html5  but the same warning actually comes up when the file is declared html4 transitional.

Any idea?

Comment: It is a bug of WTP(Eclipse Web Tools Platform). You had better submit a bug report to https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs

Comment: I will. Thanks, atlanto.

Comment: @BriceCoustillas Did you submit an eclipse bug report for this? If so, what is the bug number (or link).

Comment: @Simon Arsenault : bug 420455